# Deploying an identical war file with a different name causes the old one to stop?

Tags: java, web-services

We have an Apache tomcat server that runs a current web service. We were trying to deploy a second version (with a few tweaks) however when we copy the war file over, the first one stops working. Why??

Comment: What is different between the two ? contents of web.xml ? package names ? war file name ? pls. be more specific.

Comment: war file name is different along with some content differences in web.xml like the display name. Other than that they are very identical. Hosting people said the following: tomcat was in a hung state after the new war was put in there and had to be killed. Once we killed the tomcat processes manually, it restarted normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your webapp contain `context.xml` configuration for Tomcat? If the two webapps use the same `docbase` then they are accessing the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

If your application writes to a database, and another copy of it is competing for the same data in the same database, this can result in such behaviour.  Does your application write to a "fixed" database?  If so, you will need to create another database, or change the way the application deals with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Context root different in the war files. If not I believe the server will not validate the url correctly.

Comment: The context is the WAR file name - should be different.  You don't need to add Context to the XML